# Is there a way to grab img width value in jstl/jsp?

Tags: jsp, jstl

I am trying to grab image width from third party url and would like to question it if its width is 1px then do something. WHats the best way of doing it in JSP/JSTL? I just have image source url which deliver image sometime 1px width some time 100px width.

```
<img border="0" class="chatButton" src="http://abc.com/img.aspx">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:import var="img" url="http://abc.com/img.aspx"/>
${fn:length(img)}
```

That will give you the size of the image in bytes and give you a way to distinguish between the two images.